# Shifted, scaled and rotated coordinate system

Tags: c++, rotation, system, translation, coordinate

I have a image coordinate system and a tile coordinate system.

I would like to know the Point (u_img / v_img) in the tile coordinate system.

The coordinate system is scaled with sigma. u_img = sigma * u_tile;
The shift is given in in the tile coordinate system.
The rotation angle between the two coordinate systems is the heading.

what I want is something like (u_tile v_tile) = f( u_img, v_img, sigma, heading, u_trans, v_trans)

I started with:

```
void   image2tile( uint u_img, uint v_img,
                   int u_trans_tile, int v_trans_tile,
                   float imgPixelSize, float tilePixelSize,
                   float heading,
                   int& u_tile, int& v_tile )
{
      float ratio = imgPixelSize / tilePixelSize;
      int u_trans = u_img * ratio + u_trans_tile;
      int v_trans = v_img * ratio + v_trans_tile;

      v_tile = floor( v_trans * cos( heading ) + u_trans * sin ( heading ) );
      u_tile = floor( -v_trans * sin( heading ) + u_trans * cos ( heading ) );
}
```

There are results that seem reasonable, but if I put in u_img = 0 and v_img = 0 I should end up with u_trans_tile and v_trans_tile what actually is NOT the case.

I think the solution could look like this:

1.) transforming the translation in tile coordinates to the image coordinates 
2.) after that it was just a normal transformation using the scale factor multiplied with the rotation matrix multiplied with the point vector and added by the new translation vector.

u_trans_tile -> u_trans_img
v_trans_tile -> u_trans_img

```
  v_tile = floor( ratio*( v_img * cos( heading ) + u_img * sin ( heading ) + u_trans_img);
  u_tile = floor( ratio*(-v_img * sin( heading ) + u_img * cos ( heading ) + v_trans_img);
```

But actually I couldn't get it work.. ANY SOLUTIONS?

Comment: Is the result not the expected or is there another error? What type are `imgPixelSize` and `tilePixelSize`? If they are integers then your problem is integer division which doesn't yield the expected result.

Comment: The result is not the expected, I think my transformation is not correct.

Comment: I changed added the function header so you can see that imgPix and tilePix are both float

Comment: Have you checked that `cos(m_currGpsPos_s.heading)` returns the value that you expect? Otherwise your transform looks correct, although the code is somewhat confusing as you switched the order of `v_tile` and `u_tile`.

Comment: I edited my question, maybe this will help you. I really don't think that I have the right transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Might it be due to rounding errors caused by casting intermediate results to `int`?

This is accurate

```
  float u_trans = u_img * ratio + u_trans_tile;
  float v_trans = v_img * ratio + v_trans_tile;
```

Comment: Using `int` for `u_trans` and `v_trans` might result in a rounding, but it will maximally be 1 pixel.

Comment: Actually the transformation is wrong but this Answer also helped improving the algorithm.

Comment: @Andrey I'm sorry that my comment sounded negative. I think you pointed out an important mistake. I just wanted to add that this would result in a small error.

Comment: @yokolini: How the rotation angle is defined? Make sure it is in radians and in anticlockwise direction relative to x-axis.

Comment: It is in radian and anticockwise. The trivial result with u_img and v_img = 0 and heading = 0 is wrong!

Comment: @yokolini: could you give an example of a wrong and an expected result?